# Error that will not show itself

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a registration system for a system I am making. Currently, I am receiving a MySQL error that makes me want to tear my head out each and every time I see it.

```
 function UserRegister($user,$pass,$email,$first,$last)
 {
$sqlfirst = mysql_real_escape_string($first);
$sqllast = mysql_real_escape_string($last);
$sqluser = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$hashpass = crypt($pass);
$sqlpass = mysql_real_escape_string($hashpass);
$sqlemail = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$sql = "SELECT * 
 FROM   planerentalusers 
 WHERE  user = '$sqluser' ";
if($result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],$sql))
{   
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowcount == 1)
    {
        echo "ERROR: There is already an account with that username! Click <a href='/PHPCalTest/login.php>here </a>to login if this is you. Otherwise, go back and try a different username.";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO planerentalusers (first,last,user,pass,email) VALUES ('$sqlfirst','$sqllast','$sqluser','$sqlpass','$sqlemail')";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],$sql);
        if($result2 == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
else return false;
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Above is the function that throws the error.
there is no PHP stack trace that is being thrown, so here is what I pinpointed it to: the query is failing. But how, I do not understand. Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Try putting a semicolon at the end of your sql statement before you close your string (just to double check)?

Comment: In the page that calls the function, all it does it check if it's true or false. If false, it just says error has occurred, like I set. Otherwise it says something like "mysqli_num_rows" needs to be sent an object and not a boolean. mysqli only sends a boolean in SELECT when there is false

Comment: on the last `else` statement (before returning `false`), check the return value of the `mysqli_error` function.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$sql2` instead of `$sql` ? `$result2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],$sql);` or was that a typo ?

Comment: that looks like the problem. What @Prix said.

Comment: @Prix, yes, but that's not where the error is. Although thanks for pointing it out to me

Comment: @user2578556 so where the error is ? what line and what is the message it says and what line that is on the above code ? Preferable the error message that shows on the error log

Comment: That's not where the error is at, as stated, just a typo. As for what Carl stated, i shall try it and let you guys know

Comment: @Prix Let me editso that i can return the SQl error and I'll tell you

Comment: Your query is failing at line `$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],$sql)`. You either have problems with connection (e.g. don't have open connection or $GLOBALS['db'] doesn't hold a connection resource) or problem with query string. Do `echo $sql;` right before you call `mysqli_query()` first time and try to execute this query in mysql client.

Comment: @Prix Okay. So I feel like such an idiot. Basically, in the queries, I messed up on the field names. It took me 2 days to figure that out. Thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: @user2578556 so I was right ? or what was the error :( ? im curious

Comment: @Prix The error was, in the database, I told it to check fields that didn't exists, simply because in the script, I told it to check "user" when really in the database it was "username". This also lead me to find a bunch of other errors of the sort. In short, Carl telling me to print the error, and you telling me to check my queries, lead me to my discovery

Comment: @user2578556 LOL the names on the table were different that sucks, you should always print the errors while in development and even when you're not you can tell php to log the errors to a file which allows you to have your customized errors while keeping the real errors on the file. Glad you found the error.

Comment: Don't mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. If you're using `mysqli_query()` you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

*That is not a direct answer to your question. It has been solved somewhere between the comment lines.*

Now, you can streamline and secure your code if you will:

1. use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It's only natural since you are already using `mysqli_*` extension. Parameters that you pass to the prepared `INSERT` statement will be properly escaped.
2. utilize [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax and check for affected rows with [`affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php). That way you do all you need to do hitting your database only once.

For `INSERT IGNORE` to work properly you have to have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `username` column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE planerentalusers ADD UNIQUE (username);
```

Now if you issue an `INSERT IGNORE` statement and a username doesn't exist a row will be inserted and `affected_rows` will return `1`. If a username already exists then `IGNORE` clause will allow your `INSERT` statement to complete without throwing an error and `affected_rows` will return `0`.

That being said an improved version of your function might look like

```php
function UserRegister($db, $username, $pass, $email, $first, $last) {
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO planerentalusers (first, last, username, pass, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    // prepare the statement
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('Can\'t prepare: ' . $db->error); //TODO better error handling
    }
    // bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $first, $last, $username, $pass, $email);
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('Can\'t bind parameters: ' . $db->error); //TODO better error handling
    }
    // execute
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('Query execution failed: ' . $db->error); //TODO better error handling
    }
    // get the number of affected rows
    $affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    // close the statement
    $stmt->close();

    return $affected_rows;
}
```

and the calling code

```php
$first    = $_POST['first'];   
$last     = $_POST['last'];    
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass     = crypt($_POST['pass']);
$email    = $_POST['email'];

//create a connection to the database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $db->connect_error); //TODO better error handling
}

if (!UserRegister($db, $username, $pass, $email, $first, $last)) {
    echo "ERROR: There is already an account with that username! Click <a href='/PHPCalTest/login.php'>here </a>to login if this is you. Otherwise, go back and try a different username.";
} else {
    echo "Account successfully created";
}
```

**Note that**

1. A reference to an open db connection is explicitly passed to the function instead of using `$_GLOBALS['db']`
2. presentation logic (echoing an error message and a link) is moved out to the calling code
3. Basic error handling is implemented throughout the function